# How to load partialview into div, without the partialview being attached to a controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

How would I go about loading a partialview in a div? the partialview is not attached to a controller, its just a cshtml page that is going to be using Vue. 
I have tried using jquery's load function but keep getting 404 errors when trying to load the partialview, from the shared folder, into the div that I want to use to show it.

Right now I have a navbar that controls the content area on what is shown and not shown and there are a bunch of divs that are hidden that have @HTML.Partial, so all the partialviews are loaded up that way and its starting to be a mess, so I am looking to clear out a bunch of code and just load those partialviews on the navbar items click events

Comment: You do not directly access a `.cshtml` file. You get it via an action method. So write an action method which returns this partial view and try to request that from your JavaScript code(`load` method).

Comment: Create an action method which returns `PartialView` and use AJAX inside navbar click event handler to render it (usually done with `html()` against target placeholder).